# In corda how do I track previous life states of a LinearState asset?

Tags: corda

In a supply chain management current owner needs to track the life cycle of an asset. How do I achieve this in corda? Say the asset is a linearstate asset, which changes ownership over the time. If a current owner wants to view all the owner the asset had over the time, how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Within a flow, you can query your vault for past versions of a state using its unique identifier. For example:

```
QueryCriteria.LinearStateQueryCriteria criteria = new QueryCriteria.LinearStateQueryCriteria(
        null,
        ImmutableList.of(stateLinearId),
        // Change to `UNCONSUMED` for only unconsumed states, or `CONSUMED` for only consumed states.
        Vault.StateStatus.ALL,
        null);
Vault.Page<LinearState> results = getServiceHub().getVaultService().queryBy(LinearState.class, criteria);
List<StateAndRef<LinearState>> statesAndRefs = results.getStates();
```

You can then inspect these states to see past owners (unless the owners have used anonymous public keys to hide their identity).